# How to it is only use of kalman filter with accelerometer and magnetometer ?(LSM303C)

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, filter, kalman-filter

I have LSM303C acc and mag sensor. But my sensor is drifting. i want use kalman filter,but it usually use kalman filter with gyroscope and acc meter.

İs it possible to make with acc and mag ?

this is something i want for example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzjEMOOBuFA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason sensor fusion works so well for gyro and accelerometer is that while accelerometer provides *absolute attitude value*, the gyro provides *rate of change* of that value. So, accelerometer corrects the drift of the angle derived from gyro data, while gyro removes noise from accelerometer data.

In your case magnetometer and accelerometer basically provide two absolute attitude values in orthogonal planes (horizontal magnetic field and vertical gravity). You *might* be able to increase the precision of the magnetometer by using accelerometer data to compensate for sensor inclination, but you won't be able to eliminate drift or offset errors.

Your best option is to add gyro to the system and use Kalman filter on gyro and magnetometer data.

Comment: Thanks you for information. İ will try first low pass filter and if i dont do it, than i will use gyro and kalman filter. Thank you. :)